# Two way binding in Internet Explorer with input type=number is not working

Tags: internet-explorer, angular2-forms

the project of angular 2 is worked fine on Google Chrome however when I tried to run it on Internet Explorer the simple two way binding using [(ngModel)] is not working.

also I have installed all the polyfills those who are required in pollifills.ts

still not worked...?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: [Have you checked that the version of IE you are using is supported?](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html)

Comment: yes i have checked the version its version 10. which is not supported by Typescript compilation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe thats because The version of internet explorer that you are using dont support typescript compilation